# Groovy syntax - what is the '**' xml method-like-thingy?

Tags: xml, groovy

I found some useful xml manipulation code here:
http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html

It gives the following useful example:

```
def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(books)
def titles = response.'**'.findAll{ node-> node.name() == 'title' }*.text()
```

I get that it is a wild-card convention, but how exactly does the '**' string instruct the findAll method to search every node? What other strings would do useful things? Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shortcut for `depthFirst()`. See the API documentation for [GPathResult#getProperty(String)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html):

> Returns the specified Property of this GPathResult.
>
> Realizes the follow shortcuts:
>
> ```
> '..' for parent()
> '*' for children()
> '**' for depthFirst()
> '@' for attribute access
> ```

For how getProperty does it, here's the code from GPathResult:

```
 public Object getProperty(final String property) {
    if ("..".equals(property)) {
        return parent();
    } else if ("*".equals(property)) {
        return children();
    } else if ("**".equals(property)) {
        return depthFirst();
    } else if (property.startsWith("@")) {
        if (property.indexOf(":") != -1) {
            final int i = property.indexOf(":");
            return new Attributes(this, "@" + property.substring(i + 1), property.substring(1, i), this.namespaceTagHints);
        } else {
            return new Attributes(this, property, this.namespaceTagHints);
        }
    } else {
        if (property.indexOf(":") != -1) {
            final int i = property.indexOf(":");
            return new NodeChildren(this, property.substring(i + 1), property.substring(0, i), this.namespaceTagHints);
        } else {
            return new NodeChildren(this, property, this.namespaceTagHints);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd been expecting to see some kind of metaprogramming hackery using missingProperty or something, but that isn't required here. The call to `response.'**'` is treated as accessing a property, calling getProperty with '**' passed in as the argument.

Comment: There's no hackery, it's just a property isn't it?

Comment: @tim_yates: yes, it's just being a property, had to review how properties worked.

Answer (score 1):

That's an alias for `depthFirst`

It's documented here http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)

I can't think of anywhere else this sort of thing happens in groovy, XML parsing is a special case